# pjsua.error, error = address already in use

Tags: python, pjsip, telephony

I am trying to make calls using PJSIP module in python. For setup of SIP transport, I am doing like

```
trans_cfg = pj.TransportConfig()
# port for VoIP communication
trans_cfg.port = 5060
# local system address
trans_cfg.bound_addr = inputs.client_addr
transport = lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP,trans_cfg)
```

when I finish the call I am clearing the transport setup as, `transport = None`.

I am able to make call to user by running my program. But every time I restart my PC alone, I get an error while I run my python program

```
File "pjsuatrail_all.py", line 225, in <module>
   main()
File "pjsuatrail_all.py", line 169, in main
   transport = transport_setup()
File "pjsuatrail_all.py", line 54, in transport_setup
   transport = lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP,trans_cfg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pjsua.py", line 2304, in 
   create_transport
   self._err_check("create_transport()", self, err)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pjsua.py", line 2723, in _err_check
   raise Error(op_name, obj, err_code, err_msg)
pjsua.Error: Object: Lib, operation=create_transport(), error=Address already in use
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'" in <bound method Lib.__del__ of <pjsua.Lib instance at 0x7f8a4bbb6170>> ignored
```

For this currently I am doing like

```
$sudo lsof -t -i:5060
>> 1137
$sudo kill 1137
```

Then I run my code it works fine. 
By instance from error, I can understand that somewhere I am not closing my transport configuration properly. Can anyone help in this regards. 
[Reference code used](https://github.com/chakrit/pjsip/blob/master/pjsip-apps/src/python/samples/call.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the inputs you give, it can be understood that its not the problem with pjsip wrapper. Transport configurations looks fine.

Looking in to the 'create_transport' error, the program is not able to create the connection because 5060 port is already occupied with some other program.

For that you are killing that process and you are able to run the program with out any error. And you say it only on restart, so on your system restart some program is occupying the port.

You can try like this

```
sudo netstat -nlp|grep 5060
```

in your case it will give like

> > 1137/ProgramName

go to the 'ProgramName' in your startup configurations and make modifications such that it wont pickup the port.

Comment: command output is '1147/asterisk' , what should I do for it?  Do you mean asterisk server is blocking ?

Comment: You need to connect remotely or your PC is the asterisk server ?

Comment: I am connecting to a remote server from my PC.

Comment: Asterisk server is occupying the port, I guess your PC is the server, but I don't get it for what purpose you are creating the transport ?

Comment: I have installed the asterisk server, but I am not using it. I am trying to connect to remote server as client.

Comment: Then may be you have configured that server has to be started when you restart your PC. Check the configurations.

Comment: Ok I get it now. But how to change the configurations of the startup of the asterisk.